# highlight text in a variable using RegExp and span

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a div of text. I want to highlight some of this text stored in a variable using RegExp and span. the text to be highlighted is unknown at run time.

```js
var t = $("#highlightOutput").html(); //sentence
 var s = t.search(hStr);//what shd be replaced
 var query = new RegExp(s, "g");
 console.log(s);
 t = t.replace(query, "<span class='highlight'>"+s+ "</span>"); //problem is here
 //how to write a regex code to highlight text stored in s.
 $("#highlightOutput").html(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

`search` returns an index, but you want actual text. Use `match` for that: this method returns an array of matches, and you can take the first one.

```
var s = t.match(hStr)[0];
```